# get a value from a multikey cookie

Tags: php, arrays, database, cookies

I want to get a value from a multikey cookie!
Here's how i set my cookie:

```
setcookie("crea_camp[nome]", $nome, 0);
setcookie("crea_camp[admin]", $admin, 0);
setcookie("crea_camp[password]", $password, 0);
setcookie("crea_camp[n_part]", $n_part, 0);
setcookie("crea_camp[squadra]", $squadra, 0);
```

Now i want to get the value from the cookie n_part:

```
$n_part =$_COOKIE["crea_camp[n_part]"];
```

but it doesn't get the value!

Then other problem: all of those values I have to put them into a database, how can I do it in a fast way?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's `$n_part = $_COOKIE['crea_camp']['n_part'];`.

You may use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see the contents of a variable, for instance `print_r($_COOKIE);` and check what the key names are.

You can as well always check what cookies are set/sent back in/from the browser using the respective developer tools (Firebug, Firefox Dev Tools, Chrome Dev Tools, etc.).